Invalid token using OAuth2
I'm trying to implement oauth2 authentication system in my flutter application using flutter_appauth library and it seems to generate me an accessToken successfully, but when I call my API i get 401 unauthorized error
Here's my code
try {
      final AuthorizationTokenResponse result =
          await appAuth.authorizeAndExchangeCode(
        AuthorizationTokenRequest(
          'client_id',
          'com.app.app:/oauthredirect',
          serviceConfiguration: const AuthorizationServiceConfiguration(
           
            authorizationEndpoint: 'http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/oauth2/authorize',
            tokenEndpoint: 'http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/oauth2/token/',
            endSessionEndpoint: 'http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/oauth2/logout',
          ),
          scopes: [
            'read',
            'write',
          ],
          allowInsecureConnections: true,
        ),
      );

      if (result.accessToken != null) {
        // Debug: print access token

        if (result.accessTokenExpirationDateTime!.isBefore(DateTime.now())) {
          final TokenResponse refreshResult = await appAuth.token(TokenRequest(
              'client_id',
              'com.app.app:/oauthredirect',
              serviceConfiguration: const AuthorizationServiceConfiguration(
                
                authorizationEndpoint:
                    'http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/oauth2/authorize',
                tokenEndpoint: 'http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/oauth2/token/',
              ),
              refreshToken: result.refreshToken,
              scopes: ['read', 'write']));

          await storage.write(
            key: 'token',
            value: refreshResult.accessToken.toString(),
          );
        }

        await storage.write(
          key: 'token',
          value: result.accessToken.toString(),
        );

        // Device token registration
        String registrationIdToken = '';
        String? deviceIdToken;
        String? name;
        final deviceTokenUrl = API.deviceToken();
        final headerdevicepost = await AuthUtils.createHeaders();

        try {
          final fcmToken = await fcm.getDeviceToken();
          if (fcmToken != null) {
            registrationIdToken = fcmToken;
            debugPrint(registrationIdToken);
          }
        } catch (e) {
          debugPrint("$e debugged");
        }

        var deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
        if (Platform.isIOS) {
          var iosDeviceInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
          name = iosDeviceInfo.name;
          deviceIdToken = iosDeviceInfo.identifierForVendor;
        } else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
          var androidDeviceInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
          deviceIdToken = androidDeviceInfo.id;
          name = androidDeviceInfo.model;
        }

        Map<String, dynamic> requestBody = {
          "name": name,
          "registration_id": registrationIdToken,
          "device_id": deviceIdToken,
          "active": true,
          "type": platformType,
        };

        print(requestBody);

        if (registrationIdToken.isNotEmpty) {
          try {
            final response = await http.post(deviceTokenUrl,
                body: jsonEncode(requestBody), headers: headerdevicepost);
            if (response.statusCode == 200) {
              debugPrint(response.body);
              debugPrint("${response.statusCode}");
            } else {
              debugPrint("${response.statusCode}");
              debugPrint(response.body);
            }
          } catch (e) {
            debugPrint(e.toString());
          }
        }

        // Navigate to NavBar after successful login
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const NavBar()),
        );

        // Reset loading state
        setState(() {
          isLoading = false;
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          isLoading = false;
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
      alert(null);
    }

What can be the problem here? When I call api with a Bearer token (without oauth2) it seems to work fine, but when i use oauth2 i get 401, invalid token error
Here's the generated header when calling the API
{Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8, Authorization: Bearer VDGEK7YnXlF6CNowpiOojzEn9gE19i, X-Firebase-AppCheck: appCheck-token}

